# Recoding categorical variable in R

Tags: r, statistics

```
Let var1 = c(1,0,1,0,0,1)
    var2 = c(0,0,1,1,1,0)
    var3 = c(0,1,1,0,0,1)
    var4 = c(1,1,0,1,0,0)
```

If var1 = 0 then var2, var3 and var4 must also be 0.
How to recode these variables in R?

Answer (score 2):

Starting with a dataframe like @slava-kohut proposes it, you can even do it simpler in one line:

```r
df[df$var1 ==0,] <- 0
```

And you get:

```r
> df
  var1 var2 var3 var4
1    1    0    0    1
2    0    0    0    0
3    1    1    1    0
4    0    0    0    0
5    0    0    0    0
6    1    0    1    0
```

Comment: Yes, this is the simplest method provided there is no other variables in the actual data set (which I wasn't sure about).

Comment: I agree but here I can't extrapolate based on the question asked. Even so, if you want to only affect 0 to var2, var3 and var4, you can do `df[df$var1 == 0,c('var2','var3','var4')] <- 0`

Answer (score 2):

Another approach could be to multiply `var1` with rest of the variables. So all the values multiplied with 0 turn to 0 automatically.

```
df[-1] <- df$var1 * df[-1]

df
#  var1 var2 var3 var4
#1    1    0    0    1
#2    0    0    0    0
#3    1    1    1    0
#4    0    0    0    0
#5    0    0    0    0
#6    1    0    1    0
```

**data**

```
var1 = c(1,0,1,0,0,1)
var2 = c(0,0,1,1,1,0)
var3 = c(0,1,1,0,0,1)
var4 = c(1,1,0,1,0,0)
df <- data.frame(var1, var2, var3, var4)
```

Answer (score 1):

In base R, you can use `ifelse` for this:

```
df <- data.frame(var1 = c(1,0,1,0,0,1),
                 var2 = c(0,0,1,1,1,0),
                 var3 = c(0,1,1,0,0,1),
                 var4 = c(1,1,0,1,0,0))

df$var2 <- ifelse(df$var1 == 0, 0, df$var2)
df$var3 <- ifelse(df$var1 == 0, 0, df$var3)
df$var4 <- ifelse(df$var1 == 0, 0, df$var4)
```

If you want to use `dplyr`, then you should use `if_else` inside `mutate`:

```
df <- df %>% mutate(var2 = if_else(var1 == 0, 0, var2),
                    var3 = if_else(var1 == 0, 0, var3),
                    var4 = if_else(var1 == 0, 0, var4))
```

or a simple one-liner using `mutate_at`:

```
df <- df %>% mutate_at(c('var2', 'var3', 'var4'), ~ if_else(var1 == 0, 0, .x))
```